# Group nested array to single array in mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation

I am having an aggregation result (an array of two objects) like this:

```
[
  {
    "immunizationDetails": [
      [
        "Rubella"
      ],
      [
        "PCV13",
        "Tdap"
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "immunizationDetails": [
      [
        "Hepatitis B",
        "HIB"
      ],
      [
        "PCV13"
      ]
    ]
  }
]
```

But I need immunizationDetails to be in a single array like this:

```
[
  {
    "immunizationDetails": ["Rubella", "PCV13", "Tdap"] 
  },
  {
    "immunizationDetails": ["Hepatitis B", "HIB", "PCV13"]
  }
]
```

Need someone's valuable help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add one more `$reduce` with `$concatArrays` to flatten the result.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "immunizationDetails": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$immunizationDetails",
          "initialValue": [],
          "in": {
            "$concatArrays": [
              "$$value",
              "$$this"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zJIYKRs4z9M)